# How do you load a new html page when select an item from a <select> html element

Tags: javascript, html, select

I currently have a button for each language to allow users to view website in difference languages

```
<a href="http://www.jthink.net/songkong/en" title='English'><img src="http://static.albunack.net/images/flags/flags-iso/shiny/32/GB.png" alt="English" height="32" width="32" valign="top"></a>&nbsp;
<a href="http://www.jthink.net/songkong/de" title='Deutsch'><img src="http://static.albunack.net/images/flags/flags-iso/shiny/32/DE.png" alt="Deutsch" height="32" width="32"  valign="top"></a>&nbsp;
<a href="http://www.jthink.net/songkong/es" title='Español'><img src="http://static.albunack.net/images/flags/flags-iso/shiny/32/ES.png" alt="Español" height="32" width="32"  valign="top"></a>&nbsp;
<a href="http://www.jthink.net/songkong/fr" title='Français'><img src="http://static.albunack.net/images/flags/flags-iso/shiny/32/FR.png" alt="Français" height="32" width="32"  valign="top"></a>&nbsp;
```

I now want to use a drop down to save space

```
<select>
  <option value="en">English</option>
  <option value="de">Deutsch</option>
  <option value="es">Español</option>
  <option value="fr">Français</option>
</select>
```

but how do I make a selection trigger the correct page to be loaded

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As simple as this:

```
<select onchange="location.href='http://www.jthink.net/songkong/'+this.value;">
  <option value="en">English</option>
  <option value="de">Deutsch</option>
  <option value="es">Español</option>
  <option value="fr">Français</option>
</select>
```

Let me know if it doesn't work.

You can try unobtrusive way too:

```
<select id="langchange">
  <option value="en">English</option>
  <option value="de">Deutsch</option>
  <option value="es">Español</option>
  <option value="fr">Français</option>
</select>
```

```js
document.querySelector('#langchange').addEventListener('change', function () {
  location.href = "http://www.jthink.net/songkong/" + this.value;
});
```

Comment: Hi, just implemented and it works except the value displayed is always 'English' so if I select 'Deutsch' it goes to deutsch page but select shows 'English' which is confusing and because already set to English I cannot actually make the page go back to English, I can only change to Espanol and Francais - http://www.jthink.net/songkong/de/

Comment: You need to add `<option value="de" selected="selected">Dutch</option>` in the Dutch page.

Comment: How though, I've done it now by having a javascript function called on onload() that sets the value to the language value previously selected.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function to handle the page-change/redirect; and trigger that function once the `change` event has fired on the `<select>` element:

```
function loadNewPage () {
    // string containing the base URL to which you
    // wish the page to load:
    var baseURL = "http://www.jthink.net/songkong/",
    // the currently-selected value of the selected <option>:
        language = this.value;

    // changing the page's URL to the created URL,
    // and loading that page:
    document.location = baseURL + language;
}

// using document.querySelector() to reference the first (if any)
// <select> element on the page,
// and using addEventListener() to listen for the 'change' event,
// and assigning the loadNewPage() function to handle that event:
document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', loadNewPage);
```

References:

- [`Document.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/location).
- [`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Answer (score 0):

use this onchange attribute in your select:

```
<select onchange="window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
```

and set the value of each option to the appropriate url

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1Lnq55r8/)**